# jQuery's event.stopPropagation() causing problems with Rails :remote => true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've created some custom "popups" (initially styled with "display:none;") that are toggled via an adjacent ".popup_trigger" link with the following summarized functionality:

```
# /public/javascripts/application.js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // Trigger a popup
  jQuery('.popup_trigger').live('click', function(event) {
    jQuery(this).next('.popup').toggle(0, function() {
      // Prevent the jQuery('body').click() below if the click occurs inside the popup
      jQuery(this).click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
    return false;
  });

  // "Outside" click hides popup
  jQuery('body').click(function() {
    jQuery('.popup:visible').toggle();
  });
});
```

This works fine for displaying the popups and then hiding them when an "outside" click occurs. However, inside one such popup I have the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete medical record', medical_record, :confirm => 'Permanently delete this medical record?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
```

Which renders the following:

```
<a href="/medical_records/1" data-confirm="Permanently delete this medical record?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete medical record</a>
```

My problem is that when I trigger the popup to display, the `event.stopPropagation();` call appears to disable the remote functionality of this link. That is, when I click the link, it sends a plain old (not remote) GET request of '/medical_records/1' which looks for the show action instead of destroy.

If I comment out the `event.stopPropagation();` in my JS above, the remote link works fine, but then the popup hides when I click inside.

What can I do to have it so an active popup hides only when clicked outside of itself, and also allow the remote links to work?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue trying to modify the behavior of twitter-bootstraps' dropdown dialogs. Looking at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js, looks like they attach an event delegator to the document for data-remote objects. I'm assuming that provides a good UX when things on the page are changing, but also is annoying because it means a click on a link has to bubble up to the document. Not sure how to work around that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem: Now I use this plugin, works great:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-outside-events-plugin

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the only solution I found was to send an ajax request "manually" via jQuery like that :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#notification_<%=notification.id%> .remove-not a').on('click', function(e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '<%=notification_path(notification)%>',
        type: 'delete',
        dataType: 'script',
        success:function(data){
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

This works fine but if anyone has a better solution I'd be glad to try it out ! :)