# <div> popup hidding after click in rest of page

Tags: javascript, html

(Sorry for my english)

I got a  popup (like notifications on facebook). I wish it hidding after clicking on rest of the page.

dosent work as is should.

Can you help me?

Code:

```
<div id="login">
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#login {
background-color:@windows;
position:absolute;
width:413px;
height:190px;
z-index:110;
left:-189px;
top:43px;
overflow:visible;
line-height:normal;
display:none;
}
```

To show popup i use jquery fadeIn

JS:

```
    var active="";

function show_window(window) {
    hide_active_window();

    if(active==window) {
        active="";
        return;
    }

    active = window;

    $('#'+window).fadeIn(200);

    switch(window) {
        case 'login':
            $('#login_button').addClass("active");
            break;

    }
}

function hide_active_window() {
    if(active=="") return;

    $('#'+active).fadeOut(200);

    switch(active) {
        case 'login':
            $('#login_button').removeClass("active");
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Try this !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329816/jquery-hide-popup-if-click-detected-elsewhere

Comment: here you are, code added

Comment: how about the most important part.. your javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/tY82H/

Hope this is your answer

Jquery

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#login");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: i added my javascript code, its a bit more complikated becouse i have a lot of popups

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >
<div id="popup">My Popup</div>
<div id="restOfThePage" onClick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">Rest of the page</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gTGYU/22/)