# How to identify when a click is made outside the popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdownbox

I have a popup window which disappears on click inside, but my purpose is to make it disappear on click outside.

At the moment the popup works fine but it disappears whenever I click inside the window. When I click outside the window, it stays. How do I make it work the oppersite way around?

Code as:

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
  $('.invite_room_btn').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('.invite_room_btn'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

And HTML is:

```
<span class="invite_room_btn">
            <div class="messagepop pop">
            </div>
</span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question can be interpreted as "*how to identify when the click is made outside the popup window*"?

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it), you can work by difference, checking that the click occurred anywhere but the popup window (and eventually some other elements)

This can be achieved as follows:

the HTML code may be something like:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup"> 
    Content
    <div>DIV inside</div>
</div>
<button id="open">Open</button>
```

while the javascript is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#popup').hide()
 });

 $('#open').on('click', function () {
     $('#popup').show(500)
 });

 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
     var popup = $("#popup");
     if (!$('#open').is(e.target) && !popup.is(e.target) && popup.has(e.target).length == 0) {
         popup.hide(500);
     }
 });
```

Full example with some CSS-styling: http://jsfiddle.net/sLdmxda8/2/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the following code!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.messagepop').hide()
});


$('.invite_room_btn').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        var popup = $(".messagepop");
        popup.hide(150);
        $(".invite_room_btn").removeClass("selected");
    }
    else {
        $('.messagepop').show(150);
        $('.invite_room_btn').addClass("selected");
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var popup = $(".messagepop");
    if (!$('.invite_room_btn').is(e.target) && !popup.is(e.target) && popup.has(e.target).length == 0) {
        popup.hide(150);
 }
});
```

Thanks for the help!